# Bokeh Line Plot with HoverTool

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I want to use Bokeh HoverTool with a Line/Scatter Plot. Bellow is the code (most of it is taken from http://docs.bokeh.org/docs/gallery/correlation.html). In my example Hover displays information only for "acme" line and I cant figure out how to make it work for the other line "choam". Any suggestions/solutions ?

```
from numpy import cumprod, linspace, random
import time
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.objects import GridPlot, HoverTool

num_points = 20

now = time.time()
dt = 24*3600 
dates = linspace(now, now + num_points*dt, num_points)
acme = cumprod(random.lognormal(0.0, 0.04, size=num_points))
choam = cumprod(random.lognormal(0.0, 0.04, size=num_points))

output_file("correlation.html", title="correlation.py example")

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        acme=acme,
        choam=choam,
        dates=dates
    )
)

figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", tools="hover,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave")

hold()

line(dates, acme, color='#1F78B4', legend='ACME')
line(dates, choam, color='#FB9A99', legend='CHOAM')

scatter(dates, acme, color='#1F78B4', source = source, fill_color=None, size=8)
scatter(dates, choam, color='#33A02C', fill_color=None, size=8)

curplot().title = "Stock Returns"
grid().grid_line_alpha=0.3


hover = [t for t in curplot().tools if isinstance(t, HoverTool)][0]
hover.tooltips = OrderedDict([
    ('Price', "@acme"),
    ('Price', "@choam"),
    ('Date', "@dates"),
    ('Date', "@dates"),
])

show()
```

Comment: Your code actually seems to work for me as is with the current version of Bokeh (0.4.4)

Comment: As of (0.8.2) this doesn't work since the imports for bokeh have changed. May be easily fixable though...

Answer (score 1):

With 0.8, I used something like this for multiple plots:

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        acme=acme,
        dates=dates
    )
)

source2 = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        choam=choam,
        dates=dates
    )
)

scatter(dates, acme, color='#1F78B4', source = source1, fill_color=None, size=8)
scatter(dates, choam, color='#33A02C', source = source2, fill_color=None, size=8)
```

No assurance it will continue to work - still waiting for line tooltips :)